# How do I make my Android app load faster after splash screen?

Tags: android

After finishing coding for my app, I started to get into the optimization part. The biggest bottle-neck that I face here is loading of my app when I click on it.

It takes around 15 seconds, which it should not. The splash screen shows up for more than 15 seconds, which might make the user feel that the app has crashed. How to optimize it?

Also, what are the android optimization techniques/hacks?

Any books/blogs/answers would help. Thank you!

Comment: Please show your code for your splash screen Activity.  Its hard to say why its taking so long with nothing else to go on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/design/performance.html) android documentation, which describes how to design your app for performance. [This](http://developer.android.com/videos/index.html#v=c4znvD-7VDA) video from Google IO explains how to create smooth applications.

Do you really need to do everything you do before the user can enter the real application? Maybe you're loading too much. Maybe you're doing one particular thing wrong. 15 seconds is really a long time. There's almost nothing I can think of that should take that long to get to the screen which the user has to see.

Answer (score 0):

Rule of a thumb - do not perform long runnung tasks in onCreate() and onResume().  Do as little as necessary there,  and perform long running tasks in separate thread.   When thez are ready, you can use intent to signal your activity that new data us there